# Install Chromium on Jenkins Nodes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, chromium

I have a project which runs karma tests and need `chromium-browser` binary. For testing purposes I've manually install it with `apt install` but now that it is working I'll like to have an automatic way to install it on any Jenkins slave.

I've tried [`chromedriver-plugin`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/chromedriver-plugin) but it doesn't seem to work and not maintained for over 2 years.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [slave setup plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Slave+Setup+Plugin)

it will install the **chromium-browser** on the startup process. another option is to add the installation to the relevant job , and install the package only if it's not installed already.

BTW , how many slaves you have , did you install them manually or automatically ?

Comment: I've tried to add the shell script to the job, I got error message saying I'm not root. I have several slaves and I don't want to install manually because the next slave I'll add it will not work corrently.

Comment: How did you install the chromium manually ? Use the same commands in Jenkins script